# Return value from onClick() In returner method

Tags: android

I'm have some problem about return value from onClick method In DialogInterface.OnClickListener().
Can I return string form edittext in dialog.When I call this method in one time without assign it to other var later.

```
//Exam Code
public String getPhoneNumber(){
        String phoneNumber = "";

        AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alert.setTitle("Please input phone number");
        alert.setMessage("ex. 66898765432");
        final EditText phoneNumberEditText = new EditText(context);
        phoneNumberEditText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
        alert.setView(phoneNumberEditText);


        alert.setPositiveButton("Submit",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                    phoneNumber = phoneNumberEditText.getText().toString();
                {
        });

        alert.show();

        return phoneNumber;
}
```

in exam code it will return "" back .How I solve this problem.

Thank for all answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you are trying to return a value from the `OnClickListener`. The listener is supposed to wait for use action whereas the remaining code runs sequentially. You need to pass the value from the `OnClickListener` to some other method or to a global variable.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473940/android-best-practice-returning-values-from-a-dialog) for a discussion on various ways to achieve this.

Comment: +1, this is the correct solution.  Your method returns immediately, before phone number has been set.  Then, some time in the future, phone number is set to a value but never read after that point.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this is a side effect of your formatting or the way your code is structured, but change your `alert.setPositiveButton..` section to the following:

```
alert.setPositiveButton("Submit",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
      phoneNumber = phoneNumberEditText.getText();
    }
  });
```

Remember that `phoneNumberEditText.getText()` *already* returns a String, so you don't need `.toString()` as well. This *should* work just fine if you've entered numbers in your `AlertDialog`. [Here's](http://www.androidsnippets.com/prompt-user-input-with-an-alertdialog) a clean example you can use.

Comment: That's not true.  The `getText()` method of any `TextView` returns a `CharSequence`, so it either must be cast or call the `toString()` method to pass it into a `String` variable.