# Getting return value from onClickListener of Android

Tags: java, android, android-widget

Can I set variable into context like session in web development?

Here is my code to in which I am developing an confirmation box as soon as the Android application get started:

```
package com.example.alertboxandloadingwidgets;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Boolean result = showConfirmationBox("Are you sure you want to do this",
        this);
    }
    public Boolean showConfirmationBox(String messageToShow, final Context context) {
        // prepare the alert box
        AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        // set the message to display
        alertbox.setMessage(messageToShow);
        // set a positive/yes button and create a listener
        alertbox.setPositiveButton("Yes",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            // do something when the button is clicked
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                Toast.makeText(context,
                    "'Yes' button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
            }
        });
        // set a negative/no button and create a listener
        alertbox.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            // do something when the button is clicked
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "'No' button clicked",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        // display box
        alertbox.show();
    }
}
```

But I want that if the `yes` button is clicked then it has to return `true` and if `no` button is clicked then it has to return `false`.

But I am not able to do so because return type of `onClickListener` is void.

### Update

But the problem is that I have make it generic means This method I have to write in a CommonUtilities Class From where any of the activity can use this method. So I have to set or reset the value the result parameter from where I am calling this method.

Comment: You cannot do this.  Android dialog boxes are asynchronous, therefore you need to refactor your code accordingly.

Comment: So what approach I have to allow means I should have some common parameter in the preference. So that i have to set or reset its value.

Comment: You are thinking about it in a wrong way.  In android **there is no way** to do a synchronous blocking alert dialog.  You have to refactor it.  One way would be to have an activity instead of a dialog; invoke it for result and return different results depending on the button clicked; then handle the result in `onActivityResult`.  Believe me, if this were possible, Android would have a call like this in the standard API.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Android dialogs are asynchronous, therefore you need to refactor your code to deal with this. I'm guessing you were planning to do something like this:

```
boolean result = showConfirmation(...);
if(result) {
    //do something
}
else {
    //do something else
}
```

You can achieve the same result with something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private boolean result;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        showConfirmationBox("Are you sure you want to do this", this);
    }

    private doOnTrueResult() {
        result = true;
        //do something
    }

    private doOnFalseResult() {
        result = false;
        //do something else
    }

    public void showConfirmationBox(String messageToShow, final Context context) {

        // prepare the alert box
        AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

        // set the message to display
        alertbox.setMessage(messageToShow);

        // set a positive/yes button and create a listener
        alertbox.setPositiveButton("Yes",
        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            // do something when the button is clicked
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                Toast.makeText(context,
                    "'Yes' button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
                doOnTrueResult();
            }
        });

        // set a negative/no button and create a listener
        alertbox.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

            // do something when the button is clicked
            public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "'No' button clicked",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                doOnFalseResult();
            }
        });

        // display box
        alertbox.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir it will be the appropriate way to perform this task.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I've always handled data from dialog boxes

```
alertbox.setPositiveButton("Yes",
    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        // do something when the button is clicked
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            Toast.makeText(context,
                "'Yes' button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
               myFunction(item);
        }
    });

private void myFunction(int result){
// Now the data has been "returned" (that's not
// the right terminology)
}
```

Similarly, use another function for other Button

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass the value from `onClickListener` to a **global variable** or another method.
As you have correctly recognized the return type of `onClickListener` is *void*.
For a more complex solution take a look to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473940/android-best-practice-returning-values-from-a-dialog)

Answer (score 1):

Create a `setter` for the result value, and change the value to the selected value in your `onClick()` methods.

Make `showConfirmationBox` void ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If the function

```
public Boolean showConfirmationBox(String messageToShow, final Context context)
```

need to be called in the main thread, you cannot do it. You will never wait for user input on the main thread. That will cause ANR.

If the function can be called in background thread, you can send a message to main thread to show the alert box, and then wait for the result. Make good use of "Handler".

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that but u can create a boolean variable and store true if yes and False if no and then u can use that variable accordingly

Answer (score 1):

One simple way you could do it:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static boolean result;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        showConfirmationBox("Are you sure you want to do this", this);

    }

    public Boolean showConfirmationBox(String messageToShow, final Context context) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        alertbox.setMessage(messageToShow);
        alertbox.setPositiveButton("Yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "'Yes' button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                MainActivity.result = true;
            }
        });

    // set a negative/no button and create a listener
    alertbox.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        // do something when the button is clicked
        public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "'No' button clicked",
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            MainActivity.result = false;
        }
    });

    // display box
    alertbox.show();

    }
}
```

Comment: Make it a public static variable. Does this code already work when called from a different activity?

Comment: Actually, just looking at it, it looks like it does. So, yeah: `public static boolean result;` should work.

Answer (score 0):

one of the option would be using the

```
public Button getButton (int whichButton)
Gets one of the buttons used in the dialog.

this Returns
The button from the dialog, or null if a button does not exist.
```

for more information check the link http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html

Answer (score 0):

this may helps you

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     Boolean mresult;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

          Boolean result = showConfirmationBox("Are you sure you want to do this",this);
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    }

     public Boolean showConfirmationBox(String messageToShow, final Context context) {       

            AlertDialog.Builder alertbox = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            // set the message to display
            alertbox.setMessage(messageToShow);
            // set a positive/yes button and create a listener
            alertbox.setPositiveButton("Yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                // do something when the button is clicked
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    Toast.makeText(context,
                        "'Yes' button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();

                    mresult = true;
                }
            });
            // set a negative/no button and create a listener
            alertbox.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                // do something when the button is clicked
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "'No' button clicked",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    mresult = false;
                }
            });
            // display box
            alertbox.show();
            return mresult;
        }


}
```

Comment: Did you test this code?  It will not work as expected, because `return mresult` will be executed immediately after the dialog is displayed, not waiting for any buttons to be pressed, thus _always_ returning `false`.  `alert box.show()` is **not** blocking/modal.

Comment: @AleksG right button in here code need to botton click implement to perfome it

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your comment.  I strongly recommend that you copy/paste your code into a project and test it.