# Null Pointer Exception in Dialog for Android

Tags: android

I am trying to get a return value from a dialog and keep getting a NPE.  I have an Activity that has a button on screen.  When the button is clicked it brings up a modal with a few fields to be filled out.  When I try to get the information back to the main Activity my NPE blows up.  Here is the code:

```
public class FilterActivity extends Activity {
    final Context context = this;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_filter);

        Button addFilter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addFilter);
        addFilter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.filterName);               
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                View dialog_layout = inflater.inflate(
                        R.layout.dialog_create_filter, null);
                AlertDialog.Builder db = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        FilterActivity.this);
                db.setView(dialog_layout);

                db.setTitle("Create Filter");
                db.setPositiveButton("OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int which) {     
                                et.getText().toString();
                            }
                        });
                db.show();
            }
        });
      }
    }
```

The EditText (et) is still null when I try to get the value out of it.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks.

Comment: show the logcat output!

Comment: Please post the XML of your dialog.

Comment: have u checked the ID you have given to edittext is available in activity_filter layout

Comment: Take the EditText findViewById() code outside of onClick() and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to add `db.findViewById(R.id.filterName);` like below

```
final EditText et = (EditText) db.findViewById(R.id.filterName);
```

insted of

```
final EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.filterName);
```

full code:

```
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
                View dialog_layout = inflater.inflate(
                        R.layout.dialog_create_filter, null);
                AlertDialog.Builder db = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        FilterActivity.this);

                db.setView(dialog_layout);
                final EditText et = (EditText) db.findViewById(R.id.filterName); 

                db.setTitle("Create Filter");
                db.setPositiveButton("OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface d, int which) {     
                                et.getText().toString();
                            }
                        });
                db.show();
```

Comment: Actually there is not a method findViewById attached to a Builder, but I can create a Dialog and use the findViewById to get my EditText.  Great catch.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Where is R.id.filterName located?

Is it located in dialog_create_filter?

Then you should call findViewById only after you inflated the dialog and use the dialog_layout view as the parent.

Also take a look here:
[Android “Best Practice” returning values from a dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473940/android-best-practice-returning-values-from-a-dialog)

Hope this helps, Yaron